# Transfering files from OneDrive

Tags: download, onedrive

How do I transfer files from OneDrive back to my laptop? My system seems to be requiring me to buy more OneDrive space. I do not have access to a number of files. I would like to transfer files that are already on OneDrive back to my computer. There is plenty of storage space on the computer. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

The best course of action is to download **[OneDrive for Windows](https://onedrive.live.com/about/en-US/download/)** and sync it with your OneDrive. This way all the files get downloaded one-by-one to your hard drive.